# javascript (greasemonkey) how to access a newly created iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, greasemonkey

i have this website, by clicking on certain link on the website an iframe will be created within the same window.

my question, just wondering how to access this iframe?
i tried document.getElementById() return null
tried window.frames not there

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've given the `<iframe>` element an ID then `document.getElementById()` will work. If you're trying to get hold of its `window` object then you'll need to use the iframe element's `contentWindow` property (or use the more standard `contentDocument`, which is a reference to the iframe's `document` object but is sadly absent from IE, at least up to and including version 7):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("your_iframe_id");
var iframeWin, iframeDoc;
if (iframe.contentDocument) {
    iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    iframeWin = iframeDoc.defaultView;
} else if (iframe.contentWindow) {
    iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow;
    iframeDoc = iframeWin.document;
}
```

Comment: it gives me null

this is the iframe html

<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 739px; height: 579px;" onload="showIframe()" name="iframeContentabc" id="iframeContent" src="" hspace="0"></iframe>

,i use document.getElementById('iframeContent');  
it returns me null

Comment: just found out the code running on one of the iframe lol
document.getElementByID works
window.parent.document.getElementById

btw, with chrome window.parent will return undefined is there a workaround ?

Thx